# Excel 2010 can't move Page 1 page break

Tags: excel

I am trying to drag the page break down so more will fit on one page, but instead it just pulls down a new page break and tries to partition things into Page 1 / Page 2 / Page 3. I just want to move the darn page break down! Thanks.

Edit: I am in Page Break preview mode.

Comment: You can't.  Excel dynamically determines where to put page breaks based on font size, orientation and numerous other factors.  You can however use Fit to page which will alter font size that your content will fit to X pages wide by Y pages tall.  Page layout -->size-->more page sizes-->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using page setup scaling fit to pages.

[image]

Comment: Actually you should be able to, but what it does is adjust the scaling up or down depending on if you're exceeding content size for current font or going below it.